# ¿Como filtrar un combobox por medio de un textbox sin nigun base de datos?

Tags: c#

tengo datos en un txt ya lo cargue a un combobox pero ahora viene el problema, que no puedo filtrar los datos. si cargo el combobox desde mysql o sql server bueno alli si es facil. Pero en este caso yo quiero cargar desde un archivo txt solo no puedo filtrar.

Gracias espero que me ayuden.

Comment: Hola! para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad, te sugiero que añadas al menos lo que haz intentado para lograr lo que planteas, quizás estás cerca de lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugiero que primero llenes una lista con todos los datos que tendra el combobox, luego en el evento textchanged del textbox puedes utilizar el método contains para filtrar los elementos que buscas y luego le pasas esa lista filtrada a la propiedad Datasource del combobox.

```
    private void FilterCompany_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Si el valor no ha sido modificado por el usuario no realiza cambios
        if (!this.FilterCompany.Focused || this.FilterCompany.Text.Length < 3)
            return;
        //Obtenemos valor de búsqueda  
        string search = this.FilterCompany.Text.Trim();
        FilterCompanyByText(search);
    }

    private void FilterCompanyByText(string search)
    {
        List<ECompany> filter = new List<ECompany>();
        filter = this.Companies.Where(x => x.Company.Contains(search)).ToList();
        if (filter.Count == 0)
        {
            this.EmpresaComboBox.Text = "";
            this.AseguradoraTextBox.Text = "";
            this.CopagoTextBox.Text = "";
        }
        this.EmpresaComboBox.DataSource = filter;
        CargarEmpresa();

    }
```

En ese ejemplo el combobox lo he enlazado a un origen de datos que es una entidad llamada ECompany por eso puedo asignarle la lista de una vez. La lista Companies es la que lleno al momento de cargar el formulario y la lista filter ya con los datos filtrados.